# grep bashrc of other user for checking variable

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm trying to grep the bashrc of a user for check if a line already exists.
I've tried this:

```
if [ [ su - ${1} -c "cat ~/.bashrc | grep ${2} | wc -c | tr -d ' '"  ] -gt 0 ]
if [ su - ${1} -c "cat ~/.bashrc | grep ${2} | wc -c | tr -d ' '"  ]
```

$1 is a username

$2 is the VarName

In exec

```
+ '[' su - user -c 'cat ~/.bahsrc | grep PATH | wc -c | tr -d '\'' '\''' ']'
line xxx: [: too many arguments
```

Is it possible to do that like this ? Do I need to use return values (actually `$? = 0` for all) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just checking that a line *exists*, there's no need to involve `wc` or `tr` or anything else; this should suffice:

```
if su - ${1} -c "grep -q '${2}' ~/.bashrc" ; then
  echo line exists in file
else
  echo line does not exist in file
fi
```

This will echo `line exists in file` if the contents of `$2` are found in `~/.bashrc`.

To help understand what's going on here, remember that the syntax of the `if` statement is (from the `bash` man page):

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

Where `list` is one or more commands.  In this case, we're using the exit code from the `grep` command to determine the "truth" of the expression.